# How To Attach SessionStorage To API Configuration

Tags: next.js, shopify, shopify-app, session-storage, shopify-api

I created custom session storage and now i don't know how to add it to my api configuration which looks like this:

```
const Shopify = shopifyApi({
    apiKey: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
    apiSecretKey: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY,
    scopes: process.env.SCOPES.split(','),
    hostName: process.env.HOST.replace(/https:\/\//, ""),
    isEmbeddedApp: false,
    apiVersion: LATEST_API_VERSION
})
```

I saw how to add session storage in shopfiyApp function from
@Shopify/shopify-app-express library but I dont know how to do it in next js framework which im using in my app.

shopifyApp function example:

```
const shopify = shopifyApp({
  api: {
    apiKey: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
    apiSecretKey: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET,
    hostName: process.env.HOST.replace(/https?:\/\//, ''),
    hostScheme: 'https',
    apiVersion: LATEST_API_VERSION,
    restResources,
    scopes: process.env.SCOPES.split(","),
  },
  auth: {
    path: "/api/auth",
    callbackPath: "/api/auth/callback",
  },
  webhooks: {
    path: "/api/webhooks",
  },
  useOnlineTokens: false,
  sessionStorage: new CustomSessionStorage, // Attaching custom session storage
});
```

Comment: You could save yourself a ton of trouble and just use a working template too. Try this gents stuff. He did all the hard work so you don't have to. Just remember to be nice to him when you use his stuff. https://github.com/kinngh